# slowing down javascript autoscroll function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, autoscroll

I found this javascript autoscroll function and got it to work by pasting it in the header file of a wordpress site. However, I'd like to slow down the scroll so that it does not immediately snap to the bottom of the page.

I am brand new to javascript and could not get any other autoscroll functions to work on my site so am hoping I can just adjust this function by adding a speed variable. Many thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

    function AutoScrollOnload() {

        var InFromLeft = 172;
        var DownFromTop = 964;

        window.scrollTo(InFromLeft,DownFromTop);
    }

    function AddOnloadEvent(f) {
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = f;
        }
        else {
            var cache = window.onload;
            window.onload = function() {
                if (cache) { cache(); }
                f();
            };
        }
    }

    AddOnloadEvent(AutoScrollOnload);

//--></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Play with the values (10) to adjust to your liking.

```
function slowScroll(inFromLeft, downFromTop) {
    var left = 0;
    var top = 0;

    function scroll() {
        left = left + 10;
        top = top + 10;
        window.scrollTo(left, top);

        if (left >= inFromLeft && top >= downFromTop)
          clearInterval(id)
      }

      var id = setInterval(scroll, 10) 
    }

function AutoScrollOnload() {
    var InFromLeft = 172;
    var DownFromTop = 964;

    slowScroll(InFromLeft,DownFromTop);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising but did not work. I pasted it after the <head> tag, inside this tag: <script type="text/javascript"> </script>. I also played with the values without effect. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added inside the same `<script` the other code? `function AddOnloadEvent(f) {...`

Comment: Ah! Just made sure both were in there. Worked!